# Hide DataGridView Column

Tags: asp.net

[image]I show Grid View in my web site but i want to hide "PID" column, i try
`dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;` but its not working , this is my Database Connection code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SocialConnection"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PID , description As Post,U_Name As Name from Post ", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();          
        conn.Close();
    }
```

MarkUp :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        Width="1000px" PageIndex="2"  AllowPaging="True" > 
         <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Buttonid" runat="server"  CommandName='<%# Bind("PID") %>' Text="Rate" OnClick="Button_rate_click"></asp:Button>    
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Reply" HeaderText="Reply" Text="Reply"  />
         </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you should try make the column invisible the same way you did but after GridView1.DataBind() line

Comment: I Did it but its not working :(

Comment: can you post your gridview markup also?

Comment: This is correct, this how you hide it `ataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;` You have some other mistake.

Comment: I post the image of DataGrid

Comment: in this case, just use dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false; because the PID column is the 3rd column, if this also didn't work then you'll have to post your gridView aspx markup so that we see the design.

Comment: got it, please check the answer below it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try hiding the column from the `onRowCreated` event since it is an auto-generated column.

Add the `onRowCreated` event to your GridView markup:

```
 <asp:GridView OnRowCreated="gridView_OnRowCreated" ID="GridView2"
 runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
 Width="1000px" PageIndex="2"  AllowPaging="True" >
```

Then add the method in code-behind:

```
protected void gridView_OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //You want to remove third column (column with index 2)
    if(e.Row.Cells.Count > 2)
       e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false; // hides the first column
}
```

Hope this helps.